# I need help clarifying a high level use-case of Amazon SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

So I need a second pair of eyes to correct or confirm my understand standing of `Amazon SQS`. From my understanding, you can add an unlimited amount of messages to one queue. A message can be `256 KB` in size, and if it needs to be larger than that, you can use amazon s3 to store 2 GB. Reading around online, it appears there are many use cases for this queuing service. For example one use case of `SQS` can act as a database buffer.

But here's what I'm looking to do.. I'm looking to make a real time messaging system. My current functionality acts like more of a message board, so the implementation just inserts into the database then reads the data and packages it into `JSON` to be inserted on `SQLITE` mobile phone. That works great, but I'm getting a lot of requests from people to make it real-time.

So what I'm wondering is can I utilize amazon `SQS` to write and read messages for a chat application? So in my theoretical use case of `SQS` would have a message queue to write to, and pull from the that queue every second to check for messages on mobile. But here's where I'm confused. Since you cannot "`Query`" a particular message from the queue, would it make sense to have a queue per user then a generic queue for the app server to read from? Or am I just talking crazy and should spend cognitive resources thinking about implementing an open connection on an `Ec2` instance?

Any help would be great,

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a good use-case for SQS. Can you elaborate on what database you are using? Is it DynamoDB?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah that's what I'm thinking too. I'm using Amazon RDS, Aurora more specifically for my main DB.  I'm actually learning that amazon kinesis is meant for more of a real time data stream. So I'm thinking either create a real time stream with kinesis then add it to SQS for a data buffer into RDS. However, I did see in the docs that DynamoDB has the capacity for a stream. Maybe it might be better to use both RDS and DynamoDB for the real-time steam? Luckily the data that needs to be streamed can be normalized for NoSQL and later inserted into RDS.

Comment: DynamoDB would probably be a good thing to look into with its ability to scale read/writes based on demand. A DynamoDB stream is a bit different than a Kinesis stream because a DynamoDB stream is a essentially a log of all changes made to the DynamoDB table. This could be useful in order to notify chat participants when there are new chat messages. That may give you the near real-time performance you need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using Amazon SNS to push the chat messages to your mobile devices? Each user publishes to a topic and the readers subscribe to that topic.  You just have to be ok with missing messages if the app isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few (or maybe, less than 100) users, you could have thought of having one SQS queue per user. If that is not so, the solution won't be operationally feasible.

If you were to have one generic queue, SQS won't help because it doesn't allow querying for a given field in all available messages.

I can think of following options for your use case:

1. Setup one Redis cluster, possibly on [Amazon ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/). Have one message [List](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) per user.
2. One `Messages` table in MySQL, possibly on [AWS RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/). This will provide an easy way to query messages for a given user.
3. You can also use [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) in #2.